# Embedding CSS with jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to embed css within a HTML body using jquery. css looks like

```
.a .a101{fill:rgb(165,0,38)}
.a .a102{fill:rgb(215,48,39)}
```

I've tried the following but this is not recognized:

```
$(".a .a101").css({
    fill : 'rgb(165,0,38)'
});
$(".a .a102").css({
    fill : 'rgb(215,48,39)'
});
```

Could you kindly advice the correct way to do it?

-Regards

Comment: By HTML body, do you mean the `<body>` tag?

Comment: Can we see the HTML? Context is always helpful.

Answer (score 2):

First, I think you should start by reading carefully [the jQuery .css() method documentation](http://api.jquery.com/css/).

Then, it's actually pretty easy, you just forgot the quotation marks: `.css({'fill': 'red'})`.

FYI you can as easily do it in vanilla JS:

`document.querySelectorAll('#idForThisExample').style.fill = 'silver';`

Edit:
[Here is a working JS fiddle containing a function to loop through DOM elements](http://jsfiddle.net/b0gd0uk7/2). You will have good performances and it's good training.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to use the fill property (let's say you're using SVG):

```
$(".a .a101").css({
    'fill' : 'rgb(165,0,38)'
});
```

Assuming you want to use a background:

```
$(".a .a101").css({
    'background' : 'rgb(165,0,38)'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try `.css({background:"rgb(165,0,38})`, afaik css has no "fill" property

edit:
seems you want to fill the container with some color, you can try:

```
div{
    position:relative;
}
div.fill:before{
    background:#f00;
    content:"";
    left:0;
    height:100%;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
    z-index:2;
}
```

then

```
div.addClass("fill")
```

Comment: @Fabio true, but this really doesn't look like SVG is in play here.